# Installing Padre (IDE) on ActivePerl?

Tags: perl, strawberry-perl, activeperl, padre

When I go to Padre's official download site: http://padre.perlide.org/download.html, I see that the only option in Windows is to download DWIM Perl 5.14.2.1 (v7) **which comes with Strawberry Perl**. What if I just want to use Padre the IDE on my existing ActivePerl installation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The box right below the one you read is titled "ActiveState Perl" gives the address of a repository that has the packages for ActivePerl's `ppm` system, at least for Perl 5.12 and earlier.

```
ppm repo add http://www.wxperl.co.uk/repository
ppm install Padre
```

If you have a Perl newer than 5.12 or if you don't want to use `ppm`, you can install the modules using `cpan` as always.

```
cpan Padre
```