# Padre complains about an SQLite database issue

Tags: perl, sqlite, ubuntu-14.04, padre

I am starting with perl and wanted to install the IDE [Padre](http://padre.perlide.org/) on Ubuntu 14.04. 
[The answers in this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/674467/ubuntu-14-04-lts-what-version-of-padre-should-i-use) indicate that I simply can use `apt-get`:

```
sudo apt-get install padre
```

I also tried to install it with:

```
sudo cpan Padre
```

as indicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12270681/1771479).

However, when I run `padre`, it gives me the following error:

```
DBD::SQLite::db selectall_arrayref failed: attempt to write a readonly database at (eval 1905) line 41.
Perl exited with active threads:
    1 running and unjoined
    0 finished and unjoined
    0 running and detached
```

And when I run it as root (`sudo padre`):

```
DBD::SQLite::db do failed: Safety level may not be changed inside a transaction at (eval 1905) line 37.
Perl exited with active threads:
    1 running and unjoined
    0 finished and unjoined
    0 running and detached
```

`padre --version` shows me: `Perl Application Development and Refactoring Environment 1.00`, and my perl version is 5.18.2.

In the `/usr/bin/padre` script I do not see any reference to an SQLite database. Does anyone know how I can solve this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I found the solution in [this bug report](https://github.com/DBD-SQLite/DBD-SQLite/issues/10). In the file `Locker.pm` (in my system located in `/usr/share/perl5/Padre`) the following function (line 102) should be changed:

```
sub db_increment {
    my $self = shift;
    unless ( $self->{db_depth}++ ) {
        Padre::DB->begin;    
        # ...
        Padre::DB->pragma( synchronous => 0 );
    }
    return;
}
```

to:

```
sub db_increment {
    my $self = shift;
    unless ( $self->{db_depth}++ ) {
        #...
        Padre::DB->pragma( synchronous => 0 );
        Padre::DB->begin;
    }
    return;
}
```

i.e. changing the order of `Padre::DB->pragma` and `Padre::DB->begin`.

This allowed me to start `padre` as root (`sudo`), and to fix this I had to change the owner of the Padre configuration. I changed the rights to my user using `chown`:

```
sudo chown -R myuser:myuser /.local/share/.padre/
```